# Push_back in vector of objects from aggregate class

Tags: c++, vector, struct, aggregate, push-back

I'm having a little issue with vectors. From what I understand, `push_back()` will copy the argument and insert the copy in the vector.

```
struct BridgeData
{
    string name;
    string type;
};
```

For a simple aggregate class such as mine, the copy of an object should be made by copying both fields.

```
for ( int i = 0; i<len; i++)
{
    BridgeData data = {grp.get(1+i).asString().c_str()};
    v.push_back(data);
    cout << v[i].name << endl;
}
```

with `vector<BridgeData> &v`.

When I print `data.name`, I get the value I used in the braced list but when I print `v[i].name`, the field appears to be empty... Is the default copy "constructor" for such aggregate classes default initializing all fields?

**EDIT:**

Here's more code if that was not enough. I've got a class which contains as a data member `vector<BridgeData> yarpGroups`. I then pass it as a reference in the body of a method from the same class : `readBridgeDataVector(bGeneral,"yarpgroups",yarpGroups,numberOfYarpGroups);`.
Please ignore the other arguments as they are irrelevant (I am sure of it).
The earlier snipped is from this function :

```
void readBridgeDataVector(Bottle &rf, string name, vector<BridgeData> &v, int len)
{
    v.resize(len);
    if(rf.check(name.c_str()))
    {
        Bottle &grp = rf.findGroup(name.c_str());
        for ( int i = 0; i<len; i++)
        {
            BridgeData data = {grp.get(1+i).asString().c_str(),"float"};
            v.push_back(data);
            cout << v[0].name << endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Could not find parameters for " << name << ". "
            << "Setting everything to null by default" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see that you have ref to vector.
Perhaps the index does not match your push_back call?  (Not empty on entry?)

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure what you are trying to do should work. You'll have to post some more code / a minimal repro.

Comment: Did you provide a size for your vector at its construction ?

Comment: Indeed, the vector is passed from another function. This snipped is from a function whose goal is to `push_back` elements in it.

Comment: If you already have data in the vector your new item will go at pos *N* but you'll print out the value at pos 0 - is this your problem? Try printing out v.back().name.

Comment: @Mike Vine, you seem to be right, it prints the correct values. I am however puzzled as for where data was previously inserted in the vector. I have added some code up there as it was requested but I'm not sure it will help much... Maybe the "resize" fills `len` elements with empty `DataBridge` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've resized the vector to size **len**.

This crates **len** objects in the vector using their default constructor.

So when you `pushback()` another object it's in place **len+1**.

The object in cell 0 is actually one of the default constructed objects.

What I think you wanted to do is use **[reserve()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/)** just to have enough room for the objects.

---

**[vector::resize()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/)**

> If n is greater than the current container size, the content is
>   expanded by inserting at the end as many elements as needed to reach a
>   size of n. If val is specified, the new elements are initialized as
>   copies of val, otherwise, they are value-initialized.

**[vector::reserve()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/)**

> If n is greater than the current vector capacity, the function causes
>   the container to reallocate its storage increasing its capacity to n
>   (or greater).

Answer (score 0):

You are resizing your vector to `len` empty elements

You are then adding a new item (via `push_back`) at position `len`

You then print item at position `0` which is one of your original empty elements

Did you mean to `reserve` and not `resize`?

(Note: `reserve()` is generally *not* recommended though. Just leave your vector empty and `push_back()` the new elements you need). Also if you need to get the last element just use v.back() rather than your assumed index for ease of use.

Comment: That was exactly the issue, now fixed. Thanks a lot, I thought that by providing no secondary argument to `resize`, it would have the effect of `reserve` (I did not know about that function though).